# Upgrade AngularJS directive with ngModel to Angular component

Tags: angularjs, angular, angularjs-directive, angular-components

I am trying to upgrade my AngularJS directive to Angular Component.

Here is the code of directive:

```
ng1AppModule.component('ng1Tmp', {
    bindings: {p: '<'},
    require: {ngModel: 'ngModel'}
});
```

And I tried to upgrade it by:

```
 @Directive({selector: 'ng1-tmp'})
 class Ng1HTmpComponent extends UpgradeComponent{
     @Input() p: string;
     @Input() ngModel: INgModelController;

     constrcutor(elementRef: ElementRef, injector: Injector) {
          super('ng1Tmp', elementRef, injector);
     }
}
```

It doesn't work well. It seems not to support ngModel to upgrade in this way. But I don't see any related information in this documentation: https://angular.io/guide/upgrade .

Does anyone have some ideas on this?

Thanks in advance. :)

Comment: You should probably share what the `ng1Tmp` component in your AngularJS 1.x does exactly. That will help people answer how it should look in Angular 2+. You probably wouldn't need `super()` or `injector` in most cases, so understanding what the original component does will go a long way.

Answer (score 0):

Angular not mean new version of AngularJS, them are different struct.
3 point must known before code one component: Input, Output and EventEmitter.

One example Directive/Component here may can some help.

```
//AngularJS directive, use it like <pagination></pagination>
app.register.directive('pagination', function () {
    return {
        restrict        : 'E',
        scope           : true,
        templateUrl     : '/views/widgets/pagination.html',
        controllerAs    : 'vm',
        controller      : PaginationController
    };
    PaginationController.$inject = ['$scope'];
    function PaginationController($scope) {
    }
});
```

And now I was redefined it on Angular.

```
//Angular6 Component, use it like 
//<app-pagination [pager]="pagination" (fired)="onFire($event)"></app-pagination>
import { Component, OnInit, EventEmitter, Input, Output } from '@angular/core';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-pagination',
  templateUrl: './pagination.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./pagination.component.scss']
})
export class PaginationComponent implements OnInit {
    @Input() pager: any;
    @Output() fired = new EventEmitter<any>();

    constructor() { }

    ngOnInit() {
    }

    prev() {
        let page = this.pager.current_page - 1;
        if (page < 0) page = 1;
        this.fired.emit({type: 'page', data: page});
    }

    next() {
        let page = this.pager.current_page + 1;
        if (page > this.pager.page_count) page = this.pager.page_count;
        this.fired.emit({type: 'page', data: page});
    }

}
```

And at parent Component or Page, should be listen the event, like:

```
onFire(event) {
    switch (event.type) {
        case 'page': //pagination component fire
            return this.gotoPage(event.data);
        case 'edit': //list item fire
            return this.editArticle(event.data);
        case 'view': //list item fire
            return this.viewArticle(event.data);
        case 'trash': //list item fire
            return this.trashArticle(event.data);
    }
}
```